# Proving an ERK is of order 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

restricting your attention to scalar autonomous equations $y'=f(y)$, prove that the ERK method with tableau

\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} &0 &\frac{1}{2} \\
1& 0& 0& 1\\
\hline
& \frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{6} 
\end{array}
is of order 4.

$\mathbf{My\  attempt}:$

I am trying to prove that by Taylor expansion for the function $y$ about the point $t_n$. 
$$y(t_{n+1})=y(t_n)+hy'(t_n)+\frac{1}{2!}h^2 y''(t_n)+\frac{1}{4!}h^4 y^{(4)}(t_n)+\frac{1}{3!}h^4 y'''(t_n)+O(h^5)$$
So by the tableau above, we have \begin{align} y(t_{n+1})&=y(t_n)+h\sum_{j=1}^4w_if(t_n+h\tau_j,\epsilon_j)\\
&=y(t_n)+h[\frac{1}{6}f(t_n,\epsilon_1)+\frac{1}{3}f(t_n+\frac{1}{2}h,\epsilon_2)+\frac{1}{3}f(t_n+\frac{1}{2}h,\epsilon_3)+\frac{1}{6}f(t_n+h,\epsilon_4)] \end{align}

where $\epsilon_1=y(t_n)$, and \begin{align} &\epsilon_2=y_n+a_{2,1}f(t_n,\epsilon_1)=y_n+\frac{1}{2}f(t_n,\epsilon_1) \approx y(t_n)+\frac{1}{2}f(t_n,\epsilon_1) \\
&\epsilon_3=y_n+a_{3,1}f(t_n,\epsilon_1)+ha_{3,2}f(t_n+h\tau_2,\epsilon_2) \approx y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(t_n+\frac{h}{2},y(t_n)+\frac{1}{2}hf(t_n,y(t_n)))\\
& \epsilon_4 \approx y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(t_{n+1},[y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(t_n+\frac{1}{2}h,y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(t_n,y(t_n))])\end{align}

I know those are a lot of notation but it is what it is, I just follow the book notation. Anyway, since $y'=f(y)$, then for each term $f(t_n,y_n)=f(y_n)$, so this is what I got after some calculation  \begin{align} 
\overbrace{y(t_{n+1})}^{by\  Taylor\ expansion}&-[y(t_n)+h\sum_{j=1}^4w_if(t_n+h\tau_j,\epsilon_j)]\\
&=h [f(y(t_n))-\frac{1}{6}f(y(t_n))+\frac{1}{3}hf[y(t_n)+\frac{1}{2}hf(y(t_n))]+\\
&\frac{1}{3}hf[y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(y(t_n)+\frac{1}{2}hf(y(t_n)))]+\\
&\frac{1}{6}f[y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f([y(t_n)+
\frac{h}{2}f(y(t_n)+\frac{h}{2}f(y(t_n))])] ]+...+O(h^5)\end{align}

I am getting trouble with this calculations, I donot know if that will lead me to prove the requirement or no. I would appreciate any help with that, or if there is an easy way to show it I will really appreciate that help.

Thanks in advancwe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's just a lot of bloodletting. We have
$$\epsilon_1=f(t_n,y_n)$$
Then
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_2&=f\left(t_n+\frac h2,y_n+\frac h2\epsilon_1\right)=f(t_n,y_n)+\frac h2f_t(t_n,y_n)+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y(t_n,y_n)\\
&\quad+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}(t_n,y_n)+2\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1f_{ty}(t_n,y_n)+\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}(t_n,y_n)\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(\frac{h^3}8f_{ttt}(t_n,y_n)+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1f_{tty}(t_n,y_n)+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}(t_n,y_n)+\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}(t_n,y_n)\right)\\
&\quad+O(h^4)\\
&=\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}+2\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(\frac{h^3}8f_{ttt}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1f_{tty}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}\right)+O(h^4)\end{align}$$
Where the arguments of $f_{xx}(t_n,y_n)$ are implicit. Next up:
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_3&=f\left(t_n+\frac h2,y_n+\frac h2\epsilon_2\right)=\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_2f_y+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}+2\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_2f_{ty}+\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_2^2f_{yy}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(\frac{h^3}8f_{ttt}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_2f_{tty}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_2^2f_{tyy}+\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_2^3f_{yyy}\right)+O(h^4)\\
&=\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\left(\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}+2\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\right)\right)f_y\\
&\quad+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}+2\frac{h^2}4\left(\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y\right)f_{ty}+\frac{h^2}4\left(\epsilon_1^2+h\epsilon_1f_t+h\epsilon_1^2f_y\right)f_{yy}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(\frac{h^3}8f_{ttt}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1f_{tty}+3\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+\frac{h^3}8\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}\right)+O(h^4)\end{align}$$
And the last one is
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_4&=f\left(t_n+h,y_n+h\epsilon_3\right)=\epsilon_1+hf_t+h\epsilon_3f_y+\frac12\left(h^2f_{tt}+2h^2\epsilon_3f_{ty}+h^2\epsilon_3^2f_{yy}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(h^3f_{ttt}+3h^3\epsilon_3f_{tty}+3h^h\epsilon_3^2f_{tyy}+h^3\epsilon_3^3f_{yyy}\right)+O(h^4)\\
&=\epsilon_1+hf_t+h\left(\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\left(\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y\right)f_y\right.\\
&\quad\left.+\frac12\left(\frac{h^2}4f_{tt}+2\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\frac{h^2}4\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\right)\right)f_y\\
&\quad+\frac12\left(h^2f_{tt}+2h^2\left(\epsilon_1+\frac h2f_t+\frac h2\epsilon_1f_y\right)f_{ty}+h^2\left(\epsilon_1^2+h\epsilon_1f_t+h\epsilon_1^2f_y\right)f_{yy}\right)\\
&\quad+\frac16\left(h^3f_{ttt}+3h^3\epsilon_1f_{tty}+3h^h\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+h^3\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}\right)+O(h^4)\end{align}$$
Now we can compute
$$\begin{align}\epsilon_1+2\epsilon_2+2\epsilon_3+\epsilon_4&=6\epsilon_1+3hf_t+3h\epsilon_1f_y+h^2f_tf_y+h^2\epsilon_1f_y^2+\frac{h^3}4f_tf_y^2\\
&\quad+\frac{h^3}4\epsilon_1f_y^3+\frac{h^3}4f_{tt}f_y+\frac{5h^3}4\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+h^3\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}f_y+h^2f_{tt}\\
&\quad+2h^2\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\frac{3h^3}4f_tf_{ty}+h^2\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\tag{1}\\
&\quad+\frac{3h^3}4\epsilon_1f_tf_{yy}+\frac{h^3}4f_{ttt}+\frac{3h^3}4\epsilon_1f_{tty}\\
&\quad+\frac{3h^3}4\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+\frac{h^3}4\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}+O(h^4)\end{align}$$
So now we can take total time derivatives of $y(t)$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)=f(t_n,y_n)=\epsilon_1$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac d{dt}f(t,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=f_t+\epsilon_1f_y$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}&=f_{tt}+f_tf_y+\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\epsilon_1f_y^2+\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\\
&=f_{tt}+f_tf_y+2\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\epsilon_1f_y^2+\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{d^4y}{dt^4}&=f_{ttt}+f_{tt}f_y+f_tf_{ty}+2f_tf_{ty}+2\epsilon_1f_{tty}+f_tf_y^2+2\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+2\epsilon_1f_tf_{yy}+\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}\\
&\quad+\epsilon_1f_{tty}+\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+\epsilon_1f_tf_{yy}+2\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+2\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+\epsilon_1f_y^3+2\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}f_y+2\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}f_y\\
&\quad+\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}\\
&=f_{ttt}+f_{tt}f_y+3f_tf_{ty}+f_tf_y^2+3\epsilon_1f_{tty}+5\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+3\epsilon_1f_tf_{yy}+3\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}\\
&\quad+\epsilon_1f_y^3+4\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}f_y+\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}\end{align}$$
Applying the $4^{\text{th}}$ order Taylor polynomial
$$\begin{align}y(t_{n+1})&=y+h\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{h^2}2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{h^3}6\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}+\frac{h^4}{24}\frac{d^4y}{dt^4}\\
&=y+h\epsilon_1+\frac{h^2}2f_t+\frac{h^2}2\epsilon_1f_y+\frac{h^3}6f_{tt}+\frac{h^3}6f_tf_y+\frac{h^3}3\epsilon_1f_{ty}+\frac{h^3}6\epsilon_1f_y^2\\
&\quad+\frac{h^3}6\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}+\frac{h^4}{24}f_{ttt}+\frac{h^4}{24}f_{tt}f_y+\frac{h^4}8f_tf_{ty}+\frac{h^4}{24}f_tf_y^2+\frac{h^4}8\epsilon_1f_{tty}\tag{2}\\
&\quad+\frac{5h^4}{24}\epsilon_1f_{ty}f_y+\frac{h^4}8\epsilon_1f_tf_{yy}+\frac{h^4}8\epsilon_1^2f_{tyy}+\frac{h^4}{24}\epsilon_1f_y^3+\frac{h^4}6\epsilon_1^2f_{yy}f_y\\
&\quad+\frac{h^4}{24}\epsilon_1^3f_{yyy}+O(h^5)\end{align}$$
Quickly verifying that expression $(2)$ is $y$ plus $\frac h6$ times expression $(1)$ we have completed the proof!

I think the algebra is hard because I haven't seen anyone go crazy with orders of Runge-Kutta formulas as happens with other numerical integration formulas.

Comment: You could reduce the length of the formulas by using that $f$ does not depend on $t$ per the given task.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yeah, but I always wanted to work this out for RK4. Definitely for an autonomous system as specified the fact that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ limits the explosion of algebra that can be seen in my post. Less than half the terms above have to time derivatives. Perhaps I got a bit carried away, though :)

Comment: For a system you would have to consider that $f_{yy}$ and onwards have a tensor structure, so that the argument order matters. I use $f_{yy}[f,f]$ to denote this vector-valued bi-linear form, ultimately one would use B-tree notation.